# Adding a custom operator on Google Cloud Composer

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to add a custom operator to Google Cloud Composer (Airflow) but it doesn't seem to find the operator. I've spent quite some time on this and have tried:

- [The official docs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/plugins)
- [A working (?) example provided by Google](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/automating-infrastructure-using-cloud-composer#creating_custom_airflow_operators)
- [Solutions discussed on the mailing list (redirected from a question here)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cloud-composer-discuss/MZMmxdPbXaQ/1SufZgzqBwAJ)

I've adapted the code in the example to try to get the operator.

dags/my_dag.py

```
import datetime
from airflow import DAG
# from airflow.models import Variable
# from airflow.operators import StopInstanceOperator
from airflow.operators.my_operator import StopInstanceOperator
# [END dag_imports]

# [START dag_parameters]
INTERVAL = '@daily'
START_DATE = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 16)
PROJECT = "project"
ZONE = "zone"
INSTANCE = "instance"
DISK = "disk"
# [END dag_parameters]

# [START dag]
dag1 = DAG('backup_vm_instance',
           description='Backup a Compute Engine instance using an Airflow DAG',
           schedule_interval=INTERVAL,
           start_date=START_DATE,
           catchup=False)
# [END dag]

## Compute Engine tasks
stop_instance = StopInstanceOperator(
    project=PROJECT, zone=ZONE, instance=INSTANCE, task_id='stop_instance')
# [END operators]

# Airflow DAG definition
begin >> stop_instance
```

plugins/my_operator.py

```
import datetime
import logging
import time
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
# [END imports]


class StopInstanceOperator(BaseOperator):
  """Stops the virtual machine instance."""

  @apply_defaults
  def __init__(self, project, zone, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    self.project = project
    self.zone = zone
    self.instance = instance
    super(StopInstanceOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def execute(self, context):
    logging.info("Hello world")
    # [END stop_oper_no_xcom]

class GoogleComputeEnginePlugin(AirflowPlugin):
  """Expose Airflow operators."""

  name = 'gce_commands_plugin'
  operators = [StopInstanceOperator]
```

This is the code/structure and the error I get back on Airflow is

`Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/my_dag.py] No module named 'airflow.operators.my_operator'`

Comment: did u solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your Composer files and after cleaning the code it seems to work fine.

First thing, please make sure, that you are granted with following [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/access-control), which are required to add and update plugins:

- **storage.objectAdmin** to upload files
- **composer.environments.get** to look up the DAG destination bucket. This permission is not required when using the Cloud Storage API or gsutil

Starting from `plugins/my_operator.py`:

```
# [START imports]
import datetime
import logging
import time
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
# [END imports]

class StopInstanceOperator(BaseOperator):
  """Stops the virtual machine instance."""

  @apply_defaults
  def __init__(self, project, zone, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    self.project = project
    self.zone = zone
    self.instance = instance
    super(StopInstanceOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def execute(self, context):
    logging.info('Hello world!')

class GoogleComputeEnginePlugin(AirflowPlugin):
  """Expose Airflow operators."""

  name = 'gce_commands_plugin'
  operators = [StopInstanceOperator]
```

The code is correct, you need to put your attention to the `name = 'gce_commands_plugin'` variable, which gives the plugin the internal name `gce_commands_plugin` (so you can refer to it in DAG file) and adds one operator to it (`StopInstanceOperator`).

Than, we have `dags/my_dag.py`:

```
# [START dag_imports]
import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.gce_commands_plugin import StopInstanceOperator
# [END dag_imports]

# [START dag_parameters]
INTERVAL = '@daily'
START_DATE = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 16)
PROJECT = "project"
ZONE = "zone"
INSTANCE = "instance"
DISK = "disk"
# [END dag_parameters]

# [START dag]
dag1 = DAG('backup_vm_instance',
           description='Backup a Compute Engine instance using an Airflow DAG',
           schedule_interval=INTERVAL,
           start_date=START_DATE,
           catchup=False)
# [END dag]

# [START operators]
## Compute Engine tasks
stop_instance = StopInstanceOperator(
    project=PROJECT, zone=ZONE, instance=INSTANCE, task_id='stop_instance')
# [END operators]
```

What I noticed here:

```
from airflow.operators.my_operator import StopInstanceOperator
```

you are trying to refer to the plugin's filename, what is wrong. You have to refer to `name = 'gce_commands_plugin'` variable from your `my_operator.py` file:

```
from airflow.operators.gce_commands_plugin import StopInstanceOperator
```

You can not use following snippet of code:

```
# Airflow DAG definition
begin >> stop_instance
```

that's because you decided not to use `dummy_operator`, which defines `begin` variable.

When your files are ready, you can copy them to Composer's bucket and see positive results in Airflow UI:

```
gsutil cp $HOME/my_operator.py gs://<COMPOSER_BUCKET_NAME>/plugins

gsutil cp $HOME/my_dag.py gs://<COMPOSER_BUCKET_NAME>/dags
```

I hope it helps.